# Having trouble working with a Git repository

Tags: git, shared-hosting

Wondering if some one can help me here, I'm having a hard time learning Git.

I have shared hosting that I was able to set up Git on. I've been making commits and everything, and now I want to be able to pull(wrong vocab?) my repo down to my laptop. How do I do this? Whenever I read the examples, /path/to/files confuses me. My files and git repo are on:

```
http://abc.com/dev/project/
```

I have ssh access and everything. I have a local repository on my laptop at:

```
/Users/me/Documents/project/
```

**I guess my main question is this: Can I copy down what's on my host, work on the file on my laptop, commit the changes, then update the server with my changes?**

Comment: Just to check, when you say you have a local repository, is that the same git repository, but cloned from elsewhere?  Or did you clone that from `http://abc.com/dev/project/`?  Or is it just a copy of a code without the `.git` directory?

Comment: just did mkdir foo, then did git init. Realize now that was incorrect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git clone http://abc.com/dev/project/ $HOME/myworkdir
cd $HOME/myworkdir

// edit some stuff

git add . 
git commit -m 'edited some stuff :)'
git push origin
```

That should normally be the most simple workflow

**Update** to your comment:

It means that the remote is either a completely new (empty) repository (no harm done) or that it hasn't nominated a current branch. The first thing is fixed by pushing a new branch

```
cd ~/myworkdir
git commit --allow-empty -am 'initial commit'
git push origin master
```

If the local repository hasn't been cloned from the remote, you can

```
git push http://abc.com/dev/project/ master
```

If the local branch has another name you can use it instead of master, or

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

To push current local HEAD as the new branch master

**I recommend re-cloning your repository after the initial commit is in**; this way you get the 'conventional' clone setup (with default `origin` remote and ditto tracking branch on `master`)

Comment: Get this when I try to clone -> warning: remote HEAD refers to nonexistent ref, unable to checkout.

Comment: First person to explain it in a way I understood. Thanks very much!